# How do I send stolen files to my contractor?

Tags: hacker-experience

I took a mission to hack a target and to deliver a file. 
I downloaded the file from the target and try to leak the file to my contractor, however, the computer is constantly full and has even twice the amount of data on it that it can hold.
After a hardware reset it has space, but until I uploaded my file, it is full again and it fails.

How can I deliver the file to the contractor?

[image: picture of hacked remote target]

Comment: I think the server has a reset from time to time (maybe the software or hardware reset countdown in the corner is an indicator of that?). I would need to get back into the game to confirm that.

Comment: This is very tangential, but... this is precisely why the Steal Software missions are deceptively difficult. I would suggest taking bank missions or delete missions instead; they do not rely on waiting for hardware resets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct; it will have space on the next hardware reset.

This happens because somebody's getting a mission to DDoS this server. After a DDoS, hardware is damaged, reducing the total space. Then, when the software regenerates, it goes on the hard drive despite exceeding the space limit, resulting in the 246 / 100 you're seeing.

For NPCs, hardware (including hard drive space) will automatically regenerate once an hour, shown in the right pane under the buttons. (In your screenshot, it'll regenerate 48 minutes later.)

As soon as it regenerates, you need to upload your file. Make sure you actually complete the file upload, since if you only have it queued, when you try to complete it, the operation will fail. (I believe this happens even if you try to resolve a queued upload after a hardware reset -- the uploaded file ID will not exist.)